# Some issues when install libvirt

Tags: software-installation, libvirt

I am trying to install libvirt from source codes, my workflow is shown below,

```
#!/bin/sh
apt-get install gnutls-bin libgnutls-dev -y
apt-get install libxml++2.6-2  libxml++2.6-dev -y
apt-get install libdevmapper-dev -y
apt-get install libpciaccess-dev -y
apt-get install python-dev -y
apt-get install libnl-dev -y

if [ ! -f ./libvirt-1.1.1 ]; then
wget http://libvirt.org/sources/libvirt-1.1.1.tar.gz
fi

tar -xzvf ./libvirt-1.1.1.tar.gz
cd ./libvirt-1.1.1
./configure --prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var  --sysconfdir=/etc
make
make install
```

I have no trouble in `configure`, `make`, and `make install`. However, after `make install` finishing, when I type `virsh --version`, I get the following error message:

```
virsh: /usr/lib/libvirt.so.0: version `LIBVIRT_PRIVATE_1.1.1' not found (required by virsh)
```

I wonder what's wrong with that? Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1,use `apt-get remove --purge libvirt0` and `apt-get remove --purge libvirt-bin` to remove libvirt.

2,find anything remained concernning on "libvirt", like

```
find / -name "libvirt"
```

3,delete all of them(except for something in /sys) may work around this issue.